# Interact with facebook from flash

Tags: flash, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have looked around for tutorial how to pass facebook info to flash.

The only one thats been linked to the last past month was this.

http://ukaszblog.com/creating-facebook-flash-as3-js-application-part1-login-authorization-and-getting-user-data/

Its pretty old but does it work?  I tried it but cant get it to work, and wonder if its me or the tutorial thats to old.

/thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this one:
[Adobe: Getting started with facebook SDK and ActionScript 3.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/articles/getting-started-with-facebooksdk-actionscript3.html)

Since it's from Adobe, you can be sure it works.

Comment: I have tried that tutorial, and its work fine when I run it from flash pro.(expect it dont contact anything). But when I run it from facebook. It hangs at the init() .

Comment: Hmm this is weird... I can't help you much more since i haven't tried the tutorial but maybe you could try a minimal exemple and see if it works ? If it doesn't, post it here as i'm sure a bit of code might help you get an answer...

Comment: it was on ExternalInterface.call it got stuck, but found some help about it so working my way forward again, so tnx for pointing me in right direction